# small files in R use of RAM

Tags: r, csv, ram, xlsx

I'm trying to open a 163MB .xlsx file in R.

```
library(openxlsx)
df <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "df.xlsx", sheet = 1, colNames = T)
```

Doing this this small file (relatively small) uses all the 8GB of RAM I have on my laptop.
I have a CSV version of this file but due to the use of `,` and `;` in one of the columns using a CSV is not an option How does this happen, knowing that I recently loaded a kaggle file (a 0.5GB csv) into R and still used my laptop for browsing internet ?
Edit : the RAM usage + output of `pryr::object_size(df)`

[image]

Comment: What's the result of `pryr::object_size(df)` (you may need to `install.packages("pryr")`)?

Comment: There's two possible reasons 1. When converted to R datatypes, some fields may take up more space than they did in the original file (or less in some cases) 2. xlsx files are compressed, so expanding when loaded is expected behaviour

Comment: When you say you have a CSV version but "CSV is not an option", does that mean that your CSV is improperly formatted? It is perfectly legal to have commas and semi-colons in the file, and if formatted correctly R will read it just fine. (Perhaps you can re-export from xlsx to csv if your version is poorly-formatted and you continue to have problems reading the xlsx.)

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. @Phil I updated the post so it it includes a picture of the RAM usage and the output of `pryr::object_size(df)`

Comment: @Richard I'm not sure seeing the output of the function suggested by Phil I guess there might be another reason

Comment: @r2evans When loading the .csv some columns contains escape characters and all sorts of other characters that makes it hard to load properly into R. I guess I'll try the re-export method

Comment: *"due to the use of `,` and `;`"* is not (to me) the same as *"contains escape characters"*. If the CSV is formatted properly, then this should work fine. Are you having UTF-8/16 problems with the data? If you want to troubleshoot why loading the CSV itself is problematic, could you add to your question the top 10 lines (or so) including lines that make it a problem, as well as the errors/warnings indicating that it is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

did you try readxl package https://blog.rstudio.org/2017/04/19/readxl-1-0-0/

```
read_xlsx(path, sheet = NULL, range = NULL, col_names = TRUE,
col_types = NULL, na = "", trim_ws = TRUE, skip = 0, n_max = Inf,
guess_max = min(1000, n_max))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also read it as tab delimited (`read.csv(..., sep="\t")`) or save it as a `.txt` file and read it as tab delimited.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is (or at least was) a problem with `openxlsx`. This Github issue describes the problem of inflated file sizes and suggests a solution (use the development version): https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/161

So, potential solutions:

- Try the development version of `openxlsx` (`devtools::install_github("awalker89/openxlsx")`
- As suggested by [@Ajay Ohri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44158613/3022126), try the `readxl` package instead.
- Load the file and save it as a binary R file with `save()` or `saveRDS()`
- Try again with the `.csv` file with `readr::read_csv()` or `data.table::fread()`; both are faster than base R's `read.csv()`